# BufferedReader and BufferedWriter with Socket

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

geniuses.

I want to used socket in Java.

Here is a part of my server side code:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(this.portNum);
while (!ss.isClosed()) {
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

    System.out.println("reading");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println("read");

    System.out.println("writing");
    bw.write(this.wsp.parse(new String(sb.toString())).toJSONString());
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
    System.out.println("wrote");

    bw.close();
    br.close();
    socket.close();
}
ss.close();
```

And my client side (test) code is:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("143.248.135.60", 44450);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

System.out.println("writing");
bw.write(str);
bw.newLine();
bw.flush();
System.out.println("wrote");

System.out.println("reading");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
System.out.println("read");

br.close();
bw.close();
socket.close();
```

Both sides halt after printing "reading."

What's wrong with my codes?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your application blocks at the servers site at this point:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

Your servers will read lines until the source stream gets closed (`br.readLine()` will return `null` when the end of stream has been reached). But this doesn't happen. It seems that your're expecting just a single line here so try this instead of the loop at the server side:

```
System.out.println("reading");
String line = br.readLine();
System.out.println("read");
```

Now about the name loop on the client side: The server will close the streams and the socket immediately after it has written its own data. So `br.readLine()` will return `null` on the client side after the first line was read. So it will do what you're expecting. But it will also works if you're replacing the code as I've suggested it for the server side.

Hope it helps.

---

Edit based on the clarification of the question (need to read multiple lines):

The easiest way based on your work is to use a control character like "End of transmission" (`0x04` on ASCII).

Client code:

```
System.out.println("writing");
bw.write("Hello");
bw.newLine();
bw.write("World");
bw.newLine();
bw.write(0x04); // EOT control character
bw.newLine(); // This is needed for BufferedReader/Writer - even if we've used a EOT
bw.flush();
System.out.println("wrote");
```

Continued in the next commend...

Server code:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !(line.length() > 0 && line.charAt(0) == 0x04)) {
    sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

If you're not using ASCII or UTF8 please review your used encoding to choose the correct control character.

Comment: What if I need to get lines? Stanford parser can parse a document, list of lines.